# Unanswered questions that also appear elsewhere

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Many of our questions get repeated as GitHub issues or in other places. Once in a while it might be helpful to check here to see whether or not questions have been answered elsewhere so that they can be closed/answered here.

Here's an example: [How does the VIBRA module of SIESTA compute IR intensities?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8698/5)